# c IPv4 multicast listener for UDP not receiving packets on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, udp, multicast, ipv4

for a tool i wrote a socket based udp listener which should also be able to receive multicasts.
For IPv6 this works just fine, but IPv4 just won't work.

I use a log with IPv4 Multicast packets and send it via tcpreplay from another machine to my ubuntu machine where i run the listener. I see the packets on wireshark.

The source of the packets i am looking for is 10.21.1.98 Port 30490
The destination of the packets is 239.21.0.2 Port 30490

The compilation of my code works fine, also no errors during runtime.
I put it for testing in a standalone file, so it probably includes some for this problem useless includes.

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>  // for SIOCGSTAMP
#include <sys/ioctl.h>      // for ioctl
#include <errno.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 2048

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_in, client_in;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;

    int sockfd, n, i;
    char msgbuf[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    char src_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    socklen_t client_len;

    // create socket and bind to IP & port
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("Openening socket");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    server_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_in.sin_port = htonl(30490);
    server_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_in, sizeof(server_in)) < 0) {
        perror("Binding socket");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("Socket bound successful.\n");

    // zero out structure
    bzero(&client_in, sizeof(client_in));
    client_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // join multicast group
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("169.254.255.10");    // interface ip address
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("239.21.0.2");        // multicast dst group
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsock multicast");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("Joined Ipv4 Multicast group.\n");

    while(1) {
        printf("Listening...\n");
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, msgbuf, MAX_PACKET_SIZE, 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&client_in, &client_len);
        msgbuf[MAX_PACKET_SIZE] = '\0'; // add null terminator to end of buffer
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client_in.sin_addr.s_addr), src_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("Message received. Src IP is %s\n", src_ip);
    }
}
```

I am also unsure if i need to add ip routing to the interfaces used, since IPv6 multicasts work just fine without and adding it doesen't seem to fix my problem here.

EDIT: I am confused about the information i found online regarding the needed interface configuration for receiving multicasts on ubuntu. On the one hand there is information that simply routing the multicast address does the trick and on the other hand there are posts strictly saying IPv4 Multicast is not possible on ubuntu without additional tools like **pimd**.
Since i used libpcap in an odler version of my project and that works by itself just fine with multicasts i really am wondering where the truth lies here?

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the port numbers in the addresses in your `mreq`.  That being a local variable, its initial value is indeterminate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger 
Can you give me a codesnippet showing this? From my understanding mreq only has two members:

        struct in_addr imr_multiaddr;   /* IP multicast address of group */
        struct in_addr imr_interface;   /* local IP address of interface */

Comment: I apologize.  I was thinking that the members were of type `struct sockaddr_in`, but they are actually of type `struct in_addr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
server_in.sin_port = htonl(30490);
```

You're using `htonl`, which converts a value to 32 bits of network byte order.  The port number is a 16 bit value, so you want `htons` instead.

```
server_in.sin_port = htons(30490);
```

Comment: Changed it, still not receiving multicast frames...